# handlerOut Not Triggering in a Menu Styled <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<ul>` styled to be a menu (markup & CSS below)

```
    <ul id="TopNavigation">
        <li><a href="#" id="products" class="products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="treatments">TREATMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="clinics" class="clinics">CLINICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="onlinereservation">ONLINE RESERVATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>

#TopNavigation { position:relative; float:left; display:block; width:902px; height:48px; padding:0; list-style-type:none; margin:0; background:url(../images/topnav/tile-secbar.png) repeat-x; color:#999; font:normal 13px "Helvetica", sans-serif, Arial; }
#TopNavigation li { float:left; height:18px; margin-top:2px; padding:0; color:#999; font:normal 13px "Helvetica", sans-serif, Arial; display:block; }
```

I'm using `.hover()` of jQuery to show/hide a `<div>` for two `<a>` objects in their respective `<li>` (#products & #clinics). My problem is that the `handlerOut(eventObject)` doesn't fire if I move my mouse horizontally to either of the two `<a>` that has the `.hover()` function. (code blow, the code for the other `<a>` is just the same but the `.removeClass` etc is for #clinics)

```
$("#products").hover(function(){
            $("#HoverContainer").show(500, function(){
                $("#products").removeClass("products").addClass("products_active");
            });
        }, function(){
            $("#HoverContainer").mouseleave(function(){
                $("#HoverContainer").hide(500, function(){
                    $("#products").removeClass("products_active").addClass("products");
                });
            });
        });
```

Should I change my script code or should there be a change in the CSS and/or HTML?

Comment: You didn't include the jquery.

Comment: Update w/ code details sir. ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

You are only hiding `#HoverContainer` on `mouseleave` of `#HoverContainer`, NOT on `mouseLeave` of `#products`.  Because of this, if your mouse never enters `#HoverContainer`, it will never hide.

What I would do is define the hover on the `li`, then when hovered insert`#HoverContainer` into the `li` (this way it is part of the hover).  Then on leaving the `li` do what you have now on `mouseleave` of `#HoverContainer`.

Comment: Actually I put the .hide() on .mouseLeave() on purpose. I don't want the <div> (this is actually a menu, you see) to slide-up then I leave the <a id="products">

Comment: Well that is the problem.  You're leaving the a so it's not hiding, it only hides when you leave the `#hovercontainter`.  The way I described would hide when your mouse leaves both the `a` and the `#HoverContainer`.

Comment: I see, I'll test it out then ^ ^

Comment: I've replace the $("#HoverContainer").mouseleave() to an alert now, and it's firing. I just need to handle the handleout better ^ ^